# Asp.net uploading file

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, upload

I have a FileLoad controller as such:

```
     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

What I like to do is to upload the file to the /images/logos folder on the server once the user
selects the gif image:

```
     string uploadFolder = Server.MapPath("/images/logos/");

     string uploadfile = uploadFolder + "Image1" + ".gif";
     FileUpload1.SaveAs(uploadfile);
```

When I look at the value of uploadfile it starts with C:....

I believe it should be something like /images/logos/Image1.gif as when it completes, nothing is in the images/logos folder. Note that I do not get any errors.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: That is weird man. Do you have this virtual folder set up in IIS? May be you could put a break point at `FileUpload1.SaveAs(uploadfile);` and check what the uploadfile path is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Server.MapPath("/images/logos/") // Will map to the wwwroot folder
Server.MapPath("~/images/logos/") // Will map to the application folder
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. Is server.MapPath what I should user. As mentioned, when I test it locally, it give C:\\....

Comment: @WebDev: I would recommend using it. It's the easiest way to get either the relative ("/images") or virtual ("~/images") folder. Just remember, "/images/logos" will be a folder off of your IIS site whereas "~/images/logos" will be within your application. When you deploy to your production environment, if the wwwroot folder is on the D: drive it will map it accordingly. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath gives you the absolute path on the server based on the relative path you provide.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. If I am using the fileupload, is this what I need though? Server.MapPath?

Comment: That's one way to do it, I tend to shy away from using Server.MapPath because it's harder to test.  I usually use a configuration entry for a base directory.